# Error connecting to producer : Error: ssl.certificate.location failed

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, kafka-producer-api, node-kafka-streams

Environment Information:

- OS [e.g. Mac, Arch, Windows 10]: Windows10
- Node Version [e.g. 8.2.1]:10.4.1
- NPM Version [e.g. 5.4.2]:6.4.1
- node-rdkafka version [e.g. 2.3.3]:2.5.1

Steps to Reproduce

node-rdkafka Configuration Settings:

```
var producer = new Kafka.Producer({
  'metadata.broker.list': 'ssl-enabled-host:port no',
  'dr_cb': true,
  'security.protocol': 'SSL',
  'ssl.key.location': 'test.key',   //path to the self signed certificate
  'ssl.certificate.location': 'test.crt',  //path to certificate key.
});
```

Additional context :

The kafka producer is SSL enabled. When tried connecting the broker without the security and SSL configuration in metadata it threw `Error:timeout`.
Hence went ahead to add the configuration for enabling ssl and adding the path to SSL certificate and key as mentioned above in the configuration, but that didn ot work either throwing error which I am not able to understand below is the error:

> Error connecting to producer : Error: ssl.certificate.location failed:
>   .\ssl\ssl_rsa.c:701: error:140DC002:SSL
>   routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:

Comment: Upon debugging I found this error was thrown because the path for the certificates was not correct.This can be closed now.